# how to integrate between MONGODB & SOLR, using MONGO-CONNECTOR

Tags: mongodb, solr

- Like this I started my mongod with replSet mod

> ```
> mongod --dbpath=/home/local/ASSYST-COC/so/mongo  --replSet myrep --auth
> ```

- mongo started

  mongo -u root -p root --authenticationDatabase admin
- IN mongo already i have dbs with some collections 4.started solr

  java -jar start.jar(version 4.7)
- next mongoconnector started

  sudo python /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo-connector/mongo_connector.py -m localhost:27017 -t `http://localhost:8983/solr`  -o /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo-connector/config.txt -a root -p root -n smmc-dart.testcase  -d /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo-connector/doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py

After mongo connector started in terminal it showing like.

```
 2014-04-07 16:11:19,865 - INFO - Beginning Mongo Connector
 2014-04-07 16:11:21,335 - INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
 2014-04-07 16:11:21,469 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?     commit=true' (post) with body 'u'<commit ' in 0.159 seconds.
 2014-04-07 16:11:21,475 - INFO - MongoConnector: Empty oplog progress file.
 Exception in thread Thread-1:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 530, in __bootstrap_innerself.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo-connector/mongo_connector.py", line 204, in run
repl_set = prim_admin.command("replSetGetStatus")['set']
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 396, in command msg, allowable_errors)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 147, in _check_command_response
 raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code)
 OperationFailure: command SON([('replSetGetStatus', 1)]) failed: unauthorized

2014-04-07 16:11:22,489 - INFO - Finished `http://localhost/solr/update/?  commit=true` (post) with body 'u'<commit ' in 0.018 seconds.
```

Nothing is updating in Solr, I checked this in Solr web console interface.

Is anything I need to do?

Comment: auth is failing (per the error) - if you run without auth I assume it will work, so it would seem that you are either passing in the wrong credentials or the user is not valid to run the command - you mentioned that you started the shell, but did you try running a command (like rs.status()) to verify the user was logged in and valid?